# Is it possible to push to multiple applications with the current AppHarbor <> GitHub integration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, github, appharbor

I have one Mvc application and one WCF service. AppHarbor only supports one web application in your appharbor application. I followed the instructions about splitting the application to two different solution files. Webb.App.sln and Wcf.Service.sln. It works fine do deploy each of them separatly. In GitHub you can use the AppHarbor service hook to deploy each time a new commit is made.

Is it possible to push to multiple applications with the current AppHarbor <> GitHub integration?

Is there any other way to make the deploy from GitHub to AppHarbor automatically to each of the AppHarbor applications when there is a commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>It is not possible to push to multiple applications with the current AppHarbor <> GitHub integration.</strike>

It's a good idea though and I've recently sent GitHub a [pull request](https://github.com/github/github-services/pull/203), so it should be possible to specify a list of applications very soon. I'll post an update when it has been merged.

It's now possible to specify a comma-separated list of application slugs like so: `foo,bar,baz` when setting up the AppHarbor service on GitHub. This will push your code to all the listed applications.